# How to determine two elastic tensors are similar?

Tags: simulations, elasticity

A elastic tensor is a 3*3 symmetric matrix that determines some material property.

I have a elastic tensor A and I want to find the most similar elastic tensor B from a collection of elastic tensors {B}.

Does the correlation coefficient of two matrix could be used to find B?

If not, does it exist some characteristics in elastic tensor to determine the best similar B?

b.t.w. my elastic tensor is not just composed by E and \mu, it's like:
[C11, C12, C13;
C12, C22, C23;
C13, C23, C33;];

Thanks in advance.

(The similarity I mean is the material properties represented by elastic tensors are most similar.)

Comment: I suspect the application you have in mind is what fixes what "most similar" should mean. I would guess that you need some [matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) of the difference (or maybe $AB^{-1}$?) to be minimused, but which one is surely dependent on application.

Comment: By "similar" you mean that two matrices represent the same elastic tensor but in two different coordinate systems that are rotated with respect to each other?

Comment: Thanks for reply. The similarity I mean is the material properties represented by elastic tensors are most similar. I want to get two closest material properties.

Comment: @deeebug - I think that you would have to first provide some quantitative function (or "metric") as to precisely what you mean by "similar" because there's some degree of subjectivity involved in saying whether tensor "A" is more similar to tensor "B" or tensor "C" unless you provide such a function or metric. My idea of what is meant by "similar" tensors would probably differ from yours or another person's.Also, your definition of "(By) similarity I mean is the material properties represented by elastic tensors are most similar" is a bit circular.